# how to select dropdown option using data coming from database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

how to pre-select option from dropdown on the base of data coming from database or model to view.

I also want to save this data if change in dropdown option.

**I try this code**

```
   <select class="form-control appointment_status" >
   <option <?php if ($row['status'] == 0) { ?> selected <?php } ?> value="0">In process</option>
   <option <?php if ($row['status'] == 1) { ?> selected <?php } ?> value="1">Completed</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: so whats wrong with this code?

Comment: it is not working is there another way to write this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normally what I like to do(this goes intto your controller):

```
// Select Categories    
            $categories_options = array();
            $categories_options[0] = 'Select Categories';

            $categories_list = $this->Terms_model->get_list();

            foreach($categories_list as $cat){
                $categories_options[$cat->term_id] = $cat->title;
            }

            $data['categories_options'] = $categories_options;
```

Assuming that your passing a $data variable to your view, you will be able to display it like this:

```
<!-- Post Categories -->
    <?php
        $data = array(
            'class'     =>  'form-control js-example-basic-multiple',
            'value'     =>  set_value('categories'),
            'multiple'  =>  'multiple',
        );
    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= form_label('Categories','categories'); ?>
        <?= form_dropdown('categories[]', $categories_options, 0, $data); ?>
    </div>
```

and then to edit it(a different view):

```
<?php
        $options = array(
            ''  => 'Please select an option',
            '0' => 'In process',
            '1' => 'Completed',
        );
        $data = array('class' => 'form-control');
    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= form_label('Status', 'status'); ?>
        <?= form_dropdown('status', $options, $item->status, $data); ?>
    </div>
```

Obviously you will need to change more stuff but I'm sure it will give you a better idea and approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$status = ($row['status']) ? 'selected' : '';
echo <<<END
<option value="0" $status>In process</option>
<option value="1" $status>Completed</option>
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using class... most of dropdown components uses **active** class to definy the first element on dropdown, so just put it on which element you want and will do the trick